# Self contained Angular Template is not setting variables correctly

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build a star ranking purely in an angular template file without using controllers, I have the following code which fails, I can build this using controllers (calling setRanking method ng-click) but *I want to understand why the following code is not working*. User should be able to click on a star and all the stars up to the selected star should be highlighted.

```
 <div class="item" ng-init="user_rating = 0">
   <i 
    ng-repeat="star in [1,2,3,4,5]" 
    ng-class="(star>user_rating) && 'ion-ios-star-outline' || 'ion-ios-star'"
    ng-click="user_rating = star"></i>
    <h3>Starts: {{user_rating}} </h3>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes in this code for `'ng-class'` as like below-

```
<div class="item" ng-init="user_rating = 0">
   <i 
    ng-repeat="star in [1,2,3,4,5]" 
    ng-class="star>user_rating? 'ion-ios-star-outline': 'ion-ios-star'"
    ng-click="$parent.user_rating=star;"></i>
    <h3>Starts: {{user_rating}} </h3>
  </div>
```

I Hope this may help you..

Comment: Thanks for your response, This doesn't fix/change anything, that is just different syntax, the problem still there

Comment: @Ali Please create a plunkr. Then it will be easy to solve the issue

Comment: @Ali I have updated my answer, Check now. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the scope of the `user_rating`(as it is not getting updated).

As each `ng-repeat` creates the isolated scope, so the way you are updating `user_rating` is creating a local copy of `user_rating` associated to the local scope of each `ng-repeat`.

To fix it you can replace the code

```
ng-init="user_rating = 0"
```

with

```
ng-init="r={}; r.user_rating = 0;"
```

Also refer `user_rating` with `r.user_rating` wherever you are referring `user_rating`.

Also the correct way of using ng-class is what @Shailendra mentioned in his answer. Thanks!